# Как в работающий скрипт добавить размеры папок и файлов в каталоге?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### IDLE (Python 3.10 64-bit)
Win 10

Во рабочий скрипт:

```py
import os

path = 'E:\Мой Python\__Видеокурсы Python'
rez = sorted(os.listdir(path))
with open("out_ok.txt", "w") as file:
    for n, item in enumerate(rez):
        file.write(f"{n + 1} {item}\n")
print('Список файлов смотрим здесь - out_ok.txt ')

# поиск перечня файлов в папке и запись списка в out_ok.txt
```

Как в этот скрипт добавить возможность видеть размер каждой папки и файла в каталоге ?

Comment: Спасибо. Но нужны и размеры вложеннных папок

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, через `os` модуль

```py
import os
 
size = os.path.getsize(path)
print(size)
```

где `path` - путь к файлу или каталогу

Если встроить в скрипт

```py
with open("out_ok.txt", "w") as file:
    for n, item in enumerate(rez):
        file.write(f"{n + 1} {item} {os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, item))}\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

для файлов

```
stat = os.stat(item)
file.write(f"{n + 1} {item}\t{stat.st_size}\n")
```

Для каталогов надо считать рекурсивно сложив размеры файлов.